# Netbeans only splash screen, not opening; 14.04

Tags: netbeans

Installed Netbeans via Ubuntu Software Center. After installing, I tried opening it. It worked. But after a restart, all that comes is the splash screen. I am not getting the software workspace. Please help.

Comment: Check for lock files in the NetBeansProjects directory or where it's installed, if they exist try deleting them.

Comment: @EM-Creations, when I open the .netbeans folder under home, I could see only two directories name var and config as sub directories to 7.0 which is inside .netbeans directory. I do not know what you mean by lock files. Thanks.

Comment: That probably isn't the problem in that case. Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: @EM-Creations , it is a fresh / first install.

Comment: Maybe it's still worth reinstalling? I'm just trying to suggest possible solutions but I can't say I know they're going to work.

Comment: @EM-Creations , I see. May be it will be good to list them here. Someone else may land here and find it useful.

Comment: @EM-Creations, tried reinstalling from Ubuntu Software Center. Still the same.

Comment: Found success with downloaded script. Thanks.